# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am recieving the error:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:     in out      table ... columns long double ref char time timestamp    interval date binary national character nchar The symbol " was inserted before "EXCEPTION" to continue.
Errors: check compiler log

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE register_new_customer(
    invalid_value EXCEPTION,
    user_id CUSTOMER.CUST_ID%TYPE,
    user_forename CUSTOMER.CUST_FORENAME%TYPE,
    user_surname CUSTOMER.CUST_SURNAME%TYPE,
    user_housenumber CUSTOMER.CUST_HOUSENUMBER%TYPE,
    user_street CUSTOMER.CUST_STREET%TYPE,
    user_town CUSTOMER.CUST_TOWN%TYPE,
    user_postcode CUSTOMER.CUST_POSTCODE%TYPE,
    user_phone CUSTOMER.CUST_PHONE%TYPE,
    user_dob CUSTOMER.CUST_DOB%TYPE
    
)


AS
BEGIN
    IF user_forename = NULL THEN
    RAISE invalid_value;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO customer    (cust_id,cust_forename,cust_surname,cust_housenumber,cust_street,cust_town,cust_postcode,cust_phone,cust_dob)
    VALUES (user_id,user_forename,user_surname,user_housenumber,user_street,user_town,user_postcode,user_phone,user_dob);
    

EXCEPTION
    WHEN invalid_value THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You have entered a NULL value for something that cant be NULL');

END;
/
```

The above code is what I am running and if the invalid_value EXCEPTION is removed it works fine, but I am trying to add some basic Exception handeling to the procedure and I am not really getting anywhere. Apologies if this has been asked before as I am still very new to all of this. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should change the "=" NULL to "IS" NULL.  Not sure if that will help your issue though.

Comment: The PL/SQL data types are defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-data-types.html). 'EXCEPTION' isn't one of them. However I am interested in what values you wanted to pass and how you saw it working. Many years ago I had an idea for a [user-defined exception object](https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/exception-object.html) that you could pass similarly to your example. I never found a use for it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass an exception as an argument; you need to declare it as part of the procedure itself, not as an argument:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE register_new_customer(
    user_id CUSTOMER.CUST_ID%TYPE,
    user_forename CUSTOMER.CUST_FORENAME%TYPE,
    user_surname CUSTOMER.CUST_SURNAME%TYPE,
    user_housenumber CUSTOMER.CUST_HOUSENUMBER%TYPE,
    user_street CUSTOMER.CUST_STREET%TYPE,
    user_town CUSTOMER.CUST_TOWN%TYPE,
    user_postcode CUSTOMER.CUST_POSTCODE%TYPE,
    user_phone CUSTOMER.CUST_PHONE%TYPE,
    user_dob CUSTOMER.CUST_DOB%TYPE    
)
AS
    invalid_value EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
...
```

(And as @Gary_W said, change `= NULL` to `IS NULL`.)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qoJY4DEM) with simplified table.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you, this has worked perfectly, I really cant express how grateful I am. Sorry if this reply ends up somewhere weird im new to this site and am not sure how to reply or mark this as the answer. Thanks again and have a good day.